# Leverage browser caching not working after updating .htaccess

Tags: plugins, htaccess

I have website in WordPress and I updated my `.htaccess` file with following rule.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Now, when I checked my website performance with [Google insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/). it still giving me error for **leverage browser caching**

I have used this code

```
    add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'elated_child__remove_ver' );
    add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'elated_child__remove_ver' );

    function elated_child__remove_ver( $src ) { // Remove query strings from static resources
        if ( strpos( $src, '?f=' ) || strpos( $src, '&f=' ) ) {
            $src = remove_query_arg( 'f', $src );
        }



   return $src;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Although you are using this `.htaccess` for WordPress, it's best to head over to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) since this is more of a general coding question.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan is right, but maybe it is related to WP... what are the files you get the performance error on? are they css, js files containing  the `?ver=` query strings? if so you will always get that error because query stringed files are normally not cached by browser (or cache servers).  There's a way to remove that from files before WP loads them. Let us know if that is the issue. If not, you should take this to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @bynicolas: yes these files containing ?ver= query string . Can you please tell me what is the way to remove this

Comment: @AnkitaKashyap Has this question been resolved? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

> ...these files containing `?ver=` query string . Can you please tell me what is the way to remove this

To remove all `?ver=` and `&ver=` query strings place the following in your child theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'wpse_237671_remove_ver' );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'wpse_237671_remove_ver' );

function wpse_237671_remove_ver( $src ) { // Remove query strings from static resources
    if ( strpos( $src, '?ver=' ) || strpos( $src, '&ver=' ) ) {
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    }
    return $src;
}
```

#### Before

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://some.site/to/file.css?ver=4.6' type='text/css' />
```

#### After

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://some.site/to/file.css' type='text/css' />
```

#### Update

It looks like the [Better WordPress Minify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/) is generating the `?f=` query string. I'd recommend looking into the [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) as an alternative since this one is more up-to-date and does not generate `?f=`

Comment: I am still getting same error

Comment: May you share a screenshot of the report of this error? Also, there will be some query sting that are **necessary** to have, otherwise it could break things. If you ran the report again with this function, you've probably noticed there are less query strings listed.

Comment: p-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.css,wp-content/themes/borderland/css/custom_css.css,wp-content/themes/borderland/css/webkit_stylesheet.css,wp-content/themes/borderland-child/style.css,wp-content/plugins/profile-builder/assets/css/style-front-end.css

Comment: Sharing url is not possible for me due to some reasons

Comment: i edited my question which updated code in function.php

Comment: @AnkitaKashyap So you're using a minifying plugin. which is compressing multiple CSS files after `?f=`. You would need to leave that where it is since that could make your [Better WordPress Minify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/) break. Again, you wouldn't be able to get all of the query strings because of that reason. Don't take all of the recommendations from Google Insight or other page speed tools 100%.

Comment: @AnkitaKashyap also, there seems to be an option in _BWP Minify_ to convert your `?f=` link to a `compressed.js` file, that would be a better option IMO.

Comment: @AnkitaKashyap Updated my answer with an alternative solution to your plugin issue

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan : i am using both plugins..

Comment: @AnkitaKashyap In that case, don't use two minifying plugin, this will result in a conflict since both of them are doing the same thing. Always ensure that one plugin of each type is running.

Comment: ^ good point. Those plugins are likely just constantly rewriting the file because they don't see it as something that has existed, and the `$ver` would just keep changing since they are competing.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
if ( !is_admin() || !is_admin_bar_showing() ){
  add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
  add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
}

function _remove_script_version( $src ){
  if (preg_match("(\?ver=)", $src )){
    $parts = explode( '?', $src );
    return $parts[0];
  }else{
    return $src;
  }
}
```

This will remove the `?ver=` from the file url.  There's a conditional check to see if we are on an admin page or if we are logged in. In that case, we don't apply the filters (might be useful information when you work on your site).

Also note that this won't remove *ALL* query strings since some plugins/themes might add their own and would use other filters or hardcode it within their code base.  But you could hook that same function to those filters if they are provided (if not, you would need to edit those files manually)

For instance, you can add `add_filter( 'genesis-header', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1);`  to that filter list if you were using a genesis theme.

Comment: @NathanPowell I removed my comment because you posted an answer, but thanks for clarifying. But now you removed your answer and you comment... so!?!

Comment: Context is key on this site, without your question I felt my comments lacked clarity. I just rolled everything into one answer, hope it is useful.

Comment: I think it's better anyway to have your answer than a bunch of comments... I had deleted my question before you responded because I thought your previous answer was sufficient for me to understand, without knowing that you'd comment back to me! anyhow... I'll will remove all the comments under this question since they don't provide added value to the OT question. @NathanPowell

Comment: Lol, nah man, it's fine. Why kill a cool conversation? :)

Comment: Honestly this question needs to be edited. Who uses two minification plugins at once?

Comment: @bynicolas I see your code is similar to my answer. May you elaborate on how your code differs so I can understand it more?

Comment: Well it essentially does the same thing. The main differences are that I check if we are in the backend or if the admin bar is showing, so we only remove the query string for non logged in users. This is of course optional but might be desired for admin debugging or certain scripts. And the other difference is that you are using `remove_query_arg` and I'm using `explode` again it does the same thing but `explode` might be a little bit faster because `remove_query_arg` does a bunch of additional checks. This difference shouldn't be noticeable though. @EthanJinksO'Sullivan

Comment: @bynicolas Thanks for the update. Is there a reason why WordPress adds the `ver=x.x.x` parameters?

Comment: I'm don't know the official reason behind this, but as far as I know, `ver=` is good to debug your code, other than that, I find it being an open door for bots to scan for known security flawed scripts. There are other means to track versioning. When you build your code, it does come in handy to override the cache, but even then there are other means.  Also, if you do _need_ to use the `ver=` parameter for your script, making it available for only logged in user is a more secure practice by reducing the pool of people who can actually see that parameter. @EthanJinksO'Sullivan

Answer (score 1):

If you see the `ver=` parameter change while viewing source on your page everytime you load the page, the file being loaded is "cache busting". "Cache busting" is done so that a browser can determine if a newer version of a file it would normally cache is being used.

In WordPress, the CSS and Javascript files used for the site should be using the [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function. This can be overwritten and even removed by themes and plugins. The important part to note about this function in this context is the fourth parameter: `$ver`. If that parameter is set to change dynamically, or more commonly by changing it's value because the file was changed, the parameter will "bust" the cache, causing the browser to get the file of that name anew.

An example of this would be an update to a theme. If I change a function in the theme JavaScript file, I change it's `$ver` in the `wp_enqueue_script` function too, because I don't want someone to update the theme and not see the changes just because the browser still has the file in it's cache. I shouldn't need to change it's name for the browser to know what to find. The browser shouldn't have to look up a new file everytime it needs it either.