# Leverage browser caching

Tags: htaccess, cache

I have a Wordpress based [website](https://www.emissa.org) and I am measuring its speed using both [GTMetrics](https://gtmetrix.com/) and [google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/).

The thing is I always get this recommendation on both websites:

> Leverage browser caching

I did added the following to my .htaccess, source [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"


  # Data interchange

    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/calendar                         "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images

    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML

    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"


  # JavaScript

    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"


  # Manifest files

    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Markdown

    ExpiresByType text/markdown                         "access plus 0 seconds"


  # Media files

    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"


  # Web fonts

    # Collection
    ExpiresByType font/collection                       "access plus 1 month"

    # Embedded OpenType (EOT)
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

    # OpenType
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/otf                              "access plus 1 month"

    # TrueType
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf                              "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2                            "access plus 1 month"


  # Other

    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>
```

I also tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237671/leverage-browser-caching-not-working-after-updating-htaccess), but no luck.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your mod_expire activated in your apache.conf ? :)

Comment: I will need to check, where can I find it?

Comment: You can find the module in `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` I think.

Comment: Drill down in PageSpeed Insights to check which servers it's complaining about. It could be that you successfully enabled headers on your server - but plugins or scripts from other sites don't have those same headers set. Google Analytics and Tag Manager break their own rules about how long to set the headers for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well mate you can try out the following code in .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"

</IfModule>
```

Article Source: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/optimize-wordpress-page-load-time-by-browser-cache-leverage